# Get similarity percentage on multiple strings

Tags: python, string, similarity, sentence-similarity

Is there any function inside Python that can accept multiple rows of strings and return a percentage of how much similarity they have? something like `SequenceMatcher` but for multiple strings.

For example we have the following sentences

```
Hello how are you?
Hi how are you?
hi how are you doing?
Hey how is your day?
```

I want to be able to get a percentage based on how similar the sentences are to each other

Let's say we have these three sentences

```
Hello how are you?
Hello how are you?
Hello how are you?
```

Then we should get 100% similar

but if we have

```
Hello how are you?
Hello how are you?
hola como estats?
```

then we should get a number to around 67% similarity.

Comment: Maybe you can provide more information? What code have you tried so far and what is the expected output?

Comment: You can use `map` and `itertools.product` in order to build a similarity matrix. You'll have to define your own metric though: `map(metric, product(strings, strings))`.

Comment: Just wanted to suggest `difflib`, but apparently you already know that. How should similarity work for multiple strings, other than comparing pairwise similarity for all pairs? Can you show some example input/output?

Comment: it should return one number (which is a percentage of how similar they are together) based on the total sentences we have. I will update the question to improve my example

Comment: How is your second example "around 67%"? That's one pair with perfect similarity and two pairs with very low similarity. To me, that's more like 35-40% similarity. Or do you also want to consider the similarity of the _meaning_ of the sentence, instead of purely the similarity of words and letters?

Comment: @tobias_k I should have wrote 67%, I don't want to consider the meaning at all. just based on the characters or words

Comment: @tobias_k yea it can be calculated that way too

Comment: What other way to calculate it did you had in mind? "Two out of three are the same, thus 67%?" You should make that more clear. Also, in this case, what yould be the similarity of `A, A, B, B` compared to `A, A, B, C` (with `A`,`B`, `C` being full sentences)? Would both have 50%, or one a little more than the other?

Comment: @tobias_k I should have thought more about this before I posted it, I though there would something build in Python that I can experiment with

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `pandas` to operate with a dataframe, `itertools.combinations` to calculate the combinations of 2 strings from your list and `difflib.SequenceMatcher` for the similarity calculation:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def similarity(a,b):
    seq = SequenceMatcher(a=a, b=b)
    return seq.ratio()    

strings = ['Hello how are you?', 'Hi how are you?', 'hi how are you doing?', 'Hey how is your day?']
combinations = itertools.combinations(strings,2)

df = pd.DataFrame(list(combinations))
df['similarity'] = df.apply(lambda x: similarity(x[0],x[1]), axis=1)

df.similarity.mean()
0.68
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for thanks. It would be even better if I can convert this to Java, Looks like there is a library called JPanda for Java

Comment: Oh interesting never heard of that library. I'm not experienced in Java.

Comment: No need to use `pandas` here, `numpy` will do just fine, with less overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Naively, you can do something along these lines:

```
from collections import Counter 
from itertools import zip_longest

cases=[('Hello how are you?','Hello how are you?','Hello how are you?'),
       ('Hello how are you?','Hello how are you?','hola como estats?')]

for t in cases:    
    sums=[]
    for st in zip_longest(*t,fillvalue='|'):
        sums.append((st,(len(Counter(st))-1)/len(st)))
    print(t)
    print('\n'.join(map(str, sums)))
```

Prints:

```
('Hello how are you?', 'Hello how are you?', 'Hello how are you?')
(('H', 'H', 'H'), 0.0)
(('e', 'e', 'e'), 0.0)
(('l', 'l', 'l'), 0.0)
(('l', 'l', 'l'), 0.0)
(('o', 'o', 'o'), 0.0)
((' ', ' ', ' '), 0.0)
(('h', 'h', 'h'), 0.0)
(('o', 'o', 'o'), 0.0)
(('w', 'w', 'w'), 0.0)
((' ', ' ', ' '), 0.0)
(('a', 'a', 'a'), 0.0)
(('r', 'r', 'r'), 0.0)
(('e', 'e', 'e'), 0.0)
((' ', ' ', ' '), 0.0)
(('y', 'y', 'y'), 0.0)
(('o', 'o', 'o'), 0.0)
(('u', 'u', 'u'), 0.0)
(('?', '?', '?'), 0.0)
('Hello how are you?', 'Hello how are you?', 'hola como estats?')
(('H', 'H', 'h'), 0.3333333333333333)
(('e', 'e', 'o'), 0.3333333333333333)
(('l', 'l', 'l'), 0.0)
(('l', 'l', 'a'), 0.3333333333333333)
(('o', 'o', ' '), 0.3333333333333333)
((' ', ' ', 'c'), 0.3333333333333333)
(('h', 'h', 'o'), 0.3333333333333333)
(('o', 'o', 'm'), 0.3333333333333333)
(('w', 'w', 'o'), 0.3333333333333333)
((' ', ' ', ' '), 0.0)
(('a', 'a', 'e'), 0.3333333333333333)
(('r', 'r', 's'), 0.3333333333333333)
(('e', 'e', 't'), 0.3333333333333333)
((' ', ' ', 'a'), 0.3333333333333333)
(('y', 'y', 't'), 0.3333333333333333)
(('o', 'o', 's'), 0.3333333333333333)
(('u', 'u', '?'), 0.3333333333333333)
(('?', '?', '|'), 0.3333333333333333)
```

So you difference in the second case will be slightly less that 1/3 since there are two characters that are the same in the final Spanish sentence.

Then reduce that sequence to a total difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy` to create a pairwise similarity matrix from `itertools.product`. Then you can extract the desired similarity measure from that matrix. In any case you'd need to come up with a metric (i.e. pairwise quantifier) that suits your problem.

```
import itertools as it
import numpy as np


def similarity_check(sentences, metric):
    pairwise = np.fromiter(map(
        metric,
        it.product(sentences, sentences)),
    dtype=float).reshape(len(sentences), -1)
    # return pairwise[np.triu_indices(len(sentences), 1)].mean()  # Option 1.
    return pairwise.mean(axis=0).max()  # Option 2.


print(similarity_check([
    'Hello how are you?',
    'Hello how are you?',
    'Hello how are you?'
], lambda x: float(x[0] == x[1])))  # Plug in your own metric here.

print(similarity_check([
    'Hello how are you?',
    'Hello how are you?',
    'hola como estats?'
], lambda x: float(x[0] == x[1])))  # Plug in your own metric here.
```